# some codes in index.phtml in zend framework1

Tags: php, zend-framework

in index.phtml

```
...
<?php
$this->title = "My Albums";
$this->headTitle($this->title);
?>
...
```

Question:

1. `$this->title;` is title a property? where can I see the declaration of `$title`?
2. where can i see the declaration of this method: `$this->headTitle()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `$this->title` normalt view proprety which you can set form the controller.. like this

**indexControler**

```
$this->view->title = "Test Page";
```

and you use this in view index.phtml like this

```
 $this->title;
```

while

```
$this->headTitle($this->title);
```

this is a default view helper method to set the head title of html document.

like this

```
<head>
      <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks, but in my indexController.php, I do not have this property $title, '  public function indexAction()

    {

       $albums = new Application_Model_DbTable_Albums();
       $this->view->albums = $albums->fetchAll();

    }'

Comment: if you dont want to use this just remove this and pass direct string to this function $this->headTitle("Test Page"); you can upvote or accept if my answer is helpful for you